# Create an ORACLE query - View and union with default value

Tags: database, oracle, view, union

For a specific need, I would like to create a view by merging data from several tables and adding data by default.

More details:

I have 3 tables in my database:

- the table contracts (id_contract, name)
- the table portfolios (id_pfo, label)
- a linked table "contract_Linked_pfo" (id_contract, id_pfo, budget)

For each contract, one or several portfolios can be added with a specific budget (it's visible in the linked table).

It is possible that a contract(from the contracts table) contains no portfolio. Thus this contract is no present in the linked table

I need to create a view in order to generate a table containing:

the lines from the linked table and all lines (for the other contract) linked to all portfolio in order to obtain for example:

The lines from the linked table

id_contract: 1 - id_portfolio: 1 - value:500

id_contract: 1 - id_portfolio: 2 - value:1500

id_contract: 2 - id_portfolio: 1 - value:1000

id_contract: 2 - id_portfolio: 2 - value:3000

id_contract: 3 - id_portfolio: 1 - value:5000

And the lines from the other case

id_contract: 3 - id_portfolio: 2 - value:0

id_contract: 4 - id_portfolio: 1 - value:0

id_contract: 4 - id_portfolio: 2 - value:0

id_contract: 5 - id_portfolio: 1 - value:0

id_contract: 5 - id_portfolio: 2 - value:0

I do not know how to write that in oracle. 
I know the code for creating a view and the first step of the query. After I think that I have to do an UNION with the second part of the query.

Nevertheless I do not know how to do for the second part (adding the lines for each contract not present in the linked table for each portfolio with the budget default value 0)

Could you please help me to do it?

Many thanks in advance,

Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want *all* combinations of contracts and portfolios, no matter if the combination exist in the link table or not? If the combination exists in the link table, show the budget value from the link, otherwise show zero as budget value?

Then you can instead of `UNION ALL` use a `CROSS JOIN` to get all possible combinations, and then you `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to the link table. Something like this:

```
select c.id_contract
     , p.id_pfo
     , nvl(l.budget,0) value
  from contracts c
 cross join portfolios p
  left outer join "contract_Linked_pfo" l
      on l.id_contract = c.id_contract
     and l.id_pfo = p.id_pfo
;
```

(I've assumed your link table is mixed case identifier, since you write it as such in the question. If that's not the case, then remove the quotes ;-)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and your help :-) . The query works, but I have double results. I would like to obtain all lines from the linked table and all other lines (combinaison between the contracts table and the portfolios table) and without double lines. Thus if a line exists in the linked table, it should be not retrieved in double. If the line doesn't exist in the liked table, the budget should be put to 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieved in double"? If my answer is not correct for your requirements, then I am afraid I do not understand what you mean? The example data you show are 5 rows in contracts table (id 1 to 5) and 2 rows in portfolios table (id 1 to 2). Your desired output shows 10 rows (the 5 * 2 combinations possible), and for 5 of those rows budget is shown from the linked table, 5 of those rows do not exist in linked table and therefore give 0 budget. So for 5 rows in contracts, 2 in portfolios, 5 in linked table, desired output 10 rows, my query gives you that result, does it not?

Comment: Do you mean that you can have multiple lines in linked table for the same combination of (id_contract,id_pfo) ? If so, then what do you want for budget in those cases? The sum of the linked lines? The max?

Comment: Ok it's right that you say. I fact I forgot to update a part of your query. Many thanks for your help